# How to retrieve sensitivity labels for message through Graph API

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-sdks, microsoft-graph-mail

Currently, only GROUP entity has doc to show how to fetch label info through API. Is there way to get mail message label through Graph API Call?

ref: https://github.com/microsoftgraph/microsoft-graph-docs/blob/master/api-reference/beta/resources/group.md#properties

Comment: Looks like this is not yet present for mail messages. Please upvote this [feature request](https://microsoftgraph.uservoice.com/forums/920506-microsoft-graph-feature-requests/suggestions/38915386-allowed-set-sensitivity-option-on-mail-messages).

Comment: thanks, already made a request.

Comment: Moving this to Answer :)-

Answer (score 0):

As of now this feature is not present yet. Please raise a feature request in the [Microsoft Graph Feedback Forum](https://microsoftgraph.uservoice.com/forums/920506-microsoft-graph-feature-requests).

Here is the [link](https://microsoftgraph.uservoice.com/forums/920506-microsoft-graph-feature-requests/suggestions/41656393-add-support-to-retrieve-sensitivity-labels-for-mes) where the request is created.